# Dell Inspiron 7559 not booting

Tags: dell, inspiron

Hope somebody can help me with this one.

I've managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 in legacy mode on my brand new Dell Inspiron 7559 after removing Windows 10. After that, I created a partition with GParted and then I tried to install Windows 7 along with Ubuntu. The thing is that I had to use Window's Diskpart tool in order to make the new partition available for Windows. No luck at all: the partition wasn't recognized either. So I reboot the system and tried to boot it up with UEFI in secure mode, and now it doesn't boot at all.

All it does now is to barely show the Dell logo and then it goes black screen, and after a minute it buzzes a strange noise. I can't even see the setup or boot options, just the logo flashing once and then a black screen.

Any ideas of how I can solve this issue and reinstall Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: a video showing the issue https://youtu.be/2xSeboBhDjQ

Answer (score 3):

Well, I finally managed to get it back to work. I just pressed FN + F11 whilst booting, so the screen's output is redirected back to the laptop's LCD, rather to an external display device. After that, hit F12 to enter the boot options and make it start from either UEFI or legacy mode, but ALWAYS with secure mode off.

Comment: Why doesn't it boot with secure mode?

Comment: Pfff, I don't know mate. I wish I can answer that, but honestly I can't :\

Answer (score 0):

Keep UEFI on and Secure boot off to boot into ubuntu, it doesn't boot with secure boot because, secure boot doesn't allow ubuntu to install unsigned driver's and other necessary files.